Automatic use of aliases for relationships
I have a schema that includes, among other things, self-joins and many-to-many relationships, like this:
from typing import List, Optional
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    aliased,
    DeclarativeBase,
    Session,
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
    relationship,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.types import String

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200), nullable=False)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=True)
    parent: Mapped["Post"] = relationship('Post', foreign_keys=parent_id, remote_side=id)
    tags: Mapped[List['Tag']] = relationship('Tag', secondary='tag2post')

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

class Tag2Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag2post'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    tag_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column('tag_id', ForeignKey('tag.id'))
    tag: Mapped[Tag] = relationship(Tag, overlaps='tags')
    post_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column('post_id', ForeignKey('post.id'))
    post: Mapped[Post] = relationship(Post, overlaps='tags')
    

engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(tag_a := Tag(name='a'))
    session.add(tag_b := Tag(name='b'))
    session.add(parent := Post(title='parent', tags=[tag_a]))
    session.add(child := Post(title='child', parent=parent, tags=[tag_b]))

Now I want to write a query of the form "give me all posts with tag a and whose parent has a tag b".
I understand the "manual" way of adding aliases for each step:
    parent_alias = aliased(Post)
    parent_tag = aliased(Tag)
    parent_tag2post = aliased(Tag2Post)


    q = session.query(
        Post
    ).join(
        parent_alias, Post.parent_id == parent_alias.id
    ).join(
        parent_tag2post,
        parent_alias.id == parent_tag2post.post_id
    ).join(
        parent_tag,
        parent_tag2post.tag_id == parent_tag.id,
    ).join(
        Post.tags,
    ).filter(
        parent_tag.name == 'a',
        Tag.name == 'b',
    )
    print(q.one().title) # prints 'child'

But I'm dealing with more generic code, basically a query language that gives me the conditions:

Post.tags.name == 'b'
Post.parent.tags.name == 'a'

The code that translates the query language into JOINs now would need to introspect the relationships (like Post.tags, Post.parents, Post.parents.tags), and in each relationship replace the tables by aliases and rebuild the join conditions with the aliases... which sounds rather complicated and error-prone.
Is there an easier way? Like, maybe, telling sqlalchemy to use a relationship, but with an alias? Or is there maybe a third-party package that already does this?

This doesn't directly answer your question but I've found that anything dynamic and complicated is usually more easily done with subqueries.  Especially if you start using loaders to eager load information.  For example what if you want a post with a parent with either 'a' or 'c'?  Or a post with 'd' AND 'e' AND parent with 'b'?

def query(session):

    # Drop into core to use secondary table.
    parent_q = select(
        Tag2Post.__table__.c.post_id
    ).join(
        Tag
    ).where(Tag.name == 'a')

    child_q = select(
        Tag2Post.__table__.c.post_id
    ).join(
        Tag
    ).where(Tag.name == 'b')

    # Outermost query is kept simple and conditions can be built up with
    # `and_`, `not_`, and `or_`.
    q = select(Post).where(
        Post.id.in_(child_q),
        Post.parent_id.in_(parent_q))
    results = session.scalars(q).all()

    assert results and results[0].title == 'child'

Furthermore I have found that arbitrary tag searches and relational database are not the best match but you can use postgresql to denormalize your tags into an ARRAY column which would probably be more efficient than many subqueries.
And finally a dedicated text search server is the easiest and laziest which is what I do.

Thanks! I've also come to the conclusion that I'll probably need either IN or EXISTS subselects, otherwise filtering by the n2m-joined relationships (here tags) interferes with loading them. I have to ponder a bit more if subselects actually alleviate all of our needs for aliases.
